# macOS Catalina Notarization: "failed strict validation" error while code-signing executable created using pkg npm module

Tags: node.js, code-signing, macos-catalina, pkgbuild, notarize

I have packaged a Node.js script into an executable using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg). With the macOS catalina release, all software should be notarized by Apple. As Apple only allows `.dmg`, `.pkg` or `.app` files for distribution. I used [pkgbuild](https://medium.com/swlh/the-easiest-way-to-build-macos-installer-for-your-application-34a11dd08744) to create an OS X installer and tried following:

- **Notarizing** `.pkg`: It failed with an error: `The binary is not signed.` though it's code-signed.
- **Code-Signing binary first**: I tried to code-sign the binary(i.e. created using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)) first before notarization. It also
  failed with an error `main executable failed strict validation`.

I found [similar issue](https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/128) on GitHub for [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg). I tried multiple npm modules including [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe), [encloseJS](https://github.com/igorklopov/enclose/issues/163) with no luck.

Is there any alternative for this or shall I bundle the native Node.js binary along with my script to a pkg installer so that it'll be notarized easily?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet. The `npm` modules seem to have some bug due to which notarization is failing.

One workaround is to use the native Node.js binary to run the script by putting the shebang line at the top and making the file executable. This won't cause any Notarization warning as the text files need not be notarized.

Comment: Is there any workaround? Is nexe working?

Comment: I got this to work using https://github.com/pmq20/node-packer